# How to run batch call to stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

System which I'm working on is using stored procedures to communicate with database. Database for me is black box, only way how i can access it is via stored procedures.

In the system, each SP has class equivalent which extends `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure`. Everything is working fine till now, when I have to do bulk insert. Obviously i can execute stored procedure using 100 calls, bt is it any way how i could send batch request to database with several calls in same time?

Comment: Bulk load must be implemented inside the stored procedure, this is why it is bulk.

Comment: But you can use multi-threading, i.e thread pool not sure about 100 call in time I think you can do 4-8 calls at time depending on CPU cores count.

Comment: @VictorGubin what about insert? how you can implement bulk insert in SP? I don't thinkSP deals with collections, and i don't cunt cheating by passing collection as string and parse it inside

Comment: Check this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/cheight.htm#CHDHCBBH

Answer (score 0):

you can use jdbc batched calleable statements.

```
cs = connection.prepareCall("{call procname(?)}");
cs.setString(1, "A");
cs.addBatch();
cs.setString(1, "B");
cs.addBatch();
cs.executeBatch();
```

Comment: awesome, but how to do this if ytou are using `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure` class